# Python strings aren't equal

Tags: python

Sorry if the answer to this question may be obvious, but I'm very new to Python (just first started reading a small document about the differing structure and other things from C this morning). While practicing, I decided to make an ATM. However, something weird in the verification process happened, where it compares the input `password` to the password in a .txt file representing a user database. Despite the two strings are perfectly equal (and yes, I've checked the type, both are `class str`), my script is completely failing to compare the two correctly! I'm looking and I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but I just can't find it.

Here's the relevant bits:

```
class MockUserInterface:
    def __init__(self):
        ccn = input('Enter your Credit Card Number --> ')
        password = input('Enter the corresponding password --> ')
        self.db = MockDatabase()
        self.processUser(ccn, password)
```

`processUser(self, ccn, password)` passes ccn and password to VerifyUser to get a `False|dictionary` value...

```
class MockDatabase:
    def __init__(self):
        self.initdata = open('D:/users.txt', 'r')
        self.data = {}
        line = 0
        for user in self.initdata:
            line += 1
            splitted_line = user.split(',')
            self.data[splitted_line[0]] = {'Name' : splitted_line[1], 'Password' : splitted_line[2], 'Balance' : splitted_line[3], 'id' : line}
        self.initdata.close()

    def verifyUser(self, ccn, password):
        if ccn in self.data:
            if ccn == self.data[ccn]['Password']:
                return self.data[ccn]
            else:
                print(password, self.data[ccn]['Password'])
        else:
            print(self.data)
```

The users.txt looks like this:

```
13376669999,Jack Farenheight,sh11gl3myd1ggl3d4ggl3,90001
10419949001,Sardin Morkin,5h1s1s2w31rd,90102
12345678900,Johnathan Paul,w3ll0fh1sm4j3sty,91235
85423472912,Jacob Shlomi,s3ndm35h3b11m8,-431
59283247532,Anon Tony,r34lp0l1t1k,-9999
```

After running the script, the output is:

```
C:\Python33\python.exe D:/PythonProjects/ATM(caspomat).py
Enter your Credit Card Number --> 13376669999
Enter the corresponding password --> sh11gl3myd1ggl3d4ggl3
sh11gl3myd1ggl3d4ggl3 sh11gl3myd1ggl3d4ggl3

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Again, sorry if the answer is obvious or I'm not giving enough info!

Comment: What does the `ProcessUser` method look like in your `MockDatabase` class. This is where the error is occuring

Comment: @mou, In fact OP removed his own post, I rolled it back since it looks like an accidential action

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are comparing `ccn` to the password - not the `password` arg with the user's stored password...

```
if ccn == self.data[ccn]['Password']:
```

should be

```
if password == self.data[ccn]['Password']:
```